# Can I write a screencapture in Python

Tags: python, flash

- Are there any libraries to that can be used to write a screen capture in Python.
- Can it be made to be cross-platform?
- Is it possible to capture to video?
  And if could that be in real-time?
- Or would it be possible to directly
  generate flash movies?

Answer (score 3):

screen capture can be done with [PIL thanks to the ImageGrab module](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagegrab.htm)

For generating Flash movies, you can have a look at [ming](http://www.libming.net/FrontPage). I am not sure that it has this capability but it worths a look.

Comment: PIL's great, but unfortunately the ImageGrab module can only be used on Windows, according to their docs.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this also 
may be this [URL](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/castro/1.0.4) can help you out.

its castro !!! see the sample code below may be useful....

```
>>> from castro import Castro
>>> c = Castro()
>>> c.start()
>>> # Do something awesome!
>>> c.stop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any general purpose libraries.  I did this for windows and used some [codeproject.com](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHMB_enUS325US325&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=codeproject.com+screen+capture) code in a DLL, called from ctypes.

Video capture is probably harder; I took screenshots really fast using the trivial codeproject way and got maybe 8fps.  If that's not sufficient you are probably going to need a library that is optimized to your use case; e.g. [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) or [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) or something.  CamStudio can export flash and is OSS.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a cross-platform screen capture tool in wxPython.
See download "GeneralScreenShotWX.py" in subtopic "A Flexible Screen Capture App" 
under topic "WorkingWithImages" 
@ http://wiki.wxpython.org/WorkingWithImages#A_Flexible_Screen_Capture_App.

It's working on MSW, OS X and one Linux distro and requires no extra wxPython packages.

Answer (score 1):

One way to capture a video of the user's screen (certainly for X11, not sure about Windows) is to use gstreamer with the [ximagesrc plugin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-ximagesrc.html). There are Python bindings available [here](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/), though I haven't used gst-python before. I know [Istanbul](http://live.gnome.org/Istanbul), an open source screencasting app, uses it - viewing its source might help you.

To capture static images, I've used PyGTK before on Linux to capture the user's screen. This should also work on Windows and Mac, though I haven't tried it. Here's a small snippet:

```
import gtk
win = gtk.gdk.get_root_window()
width, height = win.get_size()
pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, width, height)
pb = pb.get_from_drawable(window, window.get_colormap(), 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height)
pb.save('path to file', 'png')
```

[See the GTK docs](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I guess all possible ways to take Python controlled screenshots are covered at https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot