# Screen recorder in python

Tags: python, video

Is there a library for making a screen recorder application in python? i think it would be fun to make somthing like that. but a library that will work on linux im using ubuntu

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1357564/576139

Answer (score 2):

Using MSS is an excellent option for screen recording using python.

For example, using this code from http://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html, I got an average fps of 60.

```
import time
import cv2
import mss
import numpy


with mss.mss() as sct:
    # Part of the screen to capture
    monitor = {'top': 40, 'left': 0, 'width': 800, 'height': 640}

    while 'Screen capturing':
        last_time = time.time()

        # Get raw pixels from the screen, save it to a Numpy array
        img = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor))

        # Display the picture
        cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy normal', img)

        # Display the picture in grayscale
        # cv2.imshow('OpenCV/Numpy grayscale',
        # cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY))

        print('fps: {0}'.format(1 / (time.time()-last_time)))

        # Press "q" to quit
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: fps reduces as soon as I increase my monitor size to full size. on doing that i get a fps of around 10-12. any solutions to that?

Comment: @D.B, thanks for the answer. Can you please also show how to save the output a .mp4 file?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no mechanism to perform screen recording in Python. However, you may be able to use Python to control one of the many existing screen recording programs:

- recorditnow
- recordmydesktop
- byzanz
- istanbul
- vnc2swf
- pyvnc2swf

Answer (score 0):

[recordscreen.py](http://www.davidrevoy.com/index.php?article65/recordscreen-py-video-and-audio-capture-for-linux-with-ffmpeg) is a command line option wrapper for **avconv** (previously for **ffmpeg**) video capturing/converting tool. Implementing this in pure Python will be too slow, but of course you can always create useful bindings for those tools, or improve existing ones, such as [AVBin](http://avbin.github.com/).